# Why does a callback method needs to return something?

Tags: java, interface, callback, return-value

I have never before seen such a thing, so let's say I have such listener object:

```
MyWhateverListener dafuqListener = new MyWhateverListener() {

  @Override
  public void onSuccessCall(String s) {
    // success call
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailCall(boolean b) {
    // fail call
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onDafuqCall(int i, boolean b) {
      // some whatever code
      return false;
  }
};
```

Everything fine, the appropriate method will be called back to, when some action succeedes, but what's with this `return` inside `onDafuqCall` method, why is it needed, where it will return something?

P.S. This interface is from an Android ads provider's SDK.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Comment: the method declares it returns a boolean.  What exactly is the issue?

Comment: man, I know what a return does, but what is its purpose inside a method of a listener?

Comment: We don't know that, you should read the documentation to find out what it means.

Comment: Why minus one? The question is not as obvious as it appears.

Comment: @Radiodef the said interface is from a closed .jar file, there is no documentation explaining all the source code, I am asking in general, what is the purpose of a return inside a callback method

Comment: It could be anything, surely? For example, perhaps you have the opportunity to deal with an event, but if you choose not to, you may return false. The event could then be propagated elsewhere.

Comment: In what IDE you're doing this, Intellij Idea / Android Studio? By default Intellij could return smth when you're implementing this. I think that this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Borislav: if there is no documentation, the only way to find out it's purpose is to check the sources.

Comment: @Yuri Eclipse with Android ADT

Comment: I know that the comment is not relevant - but throw away Eclipse and use Android Studio :) BTW Intellij Idea has built-in decompiler ;)

Comment: @Yuri please don't make me swear at you :D I am gathering info and examples, and I'm preparing to make a huge Android Studio hate thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite unclear what you ask but I'll give it a shot.

Interfaces are a way to allow objects to follow a specific pattern. They come handy, for instance, when I have an interface called "**Listener**" and five implementations:
***ActionListener, MouseListener, KeyListener, CloseListener, StateChangeListener***. 
If I want to have a method allowing the user to register a user, instead of having to make separate "**registerListener**" methods for each implementation I can have: `registerListener(Listener l)`.

Now back to your post, Interfaces may contain methods with return values, as an example if I have an interface called Event, and it contains a method called `isCanceled()` that returns boolean, then if I have an implementation called "ClickEvent" and I want to check if this event (after it has been called) is canceled by anyone or anything I'll invoke the `isCanceled()` method and that should return a value, because it is handled by the implementing object.

So to wrap this up, the return value is needed by the piece of code that calls the listener to get information. If we look in Java interfaces and their implementations we can find a ton of examples. You can check for yourself by looking into the java.uti.List interface source and an implementation like java.util.ArrayList

More information can be obtained from the Docs:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

**EDIT #1:** Here is the example explained above, represented in code:

The event interface:

```
package com.fillpant.examples;

public interface Event {

    public boolean isCanceled();
    public void setCanceled(boolean value);

}
```

The ClickEvent (that implements Event):

```
package com.fillpant.examples;

public class ClickEvent implements Event {

    private boolean canceled = false;

    @Override
    public boolean isCanceled() {
        return canceled;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCanceled(boolean value) {
        canceled = value;
    }

}
```

The place where ClickEvent is called. Here I demonstrate why the return value is needed (See the `isCanceled()` method):

```
package com.fillpant.examples;

public class EventCaller {
//This class calls an event, and all the listeners will have to handle it;

    public void callClickEvent(){
        Event e = new ClickEvent();
        for(Listener l : all_registered_listeners){//this is hypothetical, if we had listeners.
            l.event(e);
        }
        if(e.isCanceled()) return;
        else{
            //DoStuff
        }
    }

}
```

If you have any question don't hesitate to ask :D

Comment: but where does the callback method returns that value from the 'return'?

Comment: I think the question is "why does a callback method need to return something?"

Comment: i didnt get that sorry, Wait ill code an example for you :D

Comment: @BalkrishnaRawool exactly what I meant, you explained it more clearly

Comment: There you go! i added the example :- )

Answer (score 4):

This is really quite a normal thing. A listener/observer interface is paired with a subject/event throwing class. Often you want your listeners to be totally disconnected from the behaviour of the subject, to the extent that the subject neither knows nor cares about how many listeners are registered. This is the 'pure' pattern. And this is the most common and it makes sense for all the methods to be void, since they are called only by the subject and the subjects behaviour does not depend on its listeners.

However, sometimes it makes sense for a listener to have other methods not intended to be called by the subject, and for the listener to act as a bridge between the state of the subject and some other part of the program. One common example is making special listeners for debugging. Here you make a new listener which extends your previous listener but it also keeps track of exactly when it is called by a subject, it then has a method with a return value so that your testing code can access this state, and see exactly what that listener was doing.

Finally, it occasionally makes sense to have listeners which affect the behaviour of the subject. In this case return methods are necessary. But this is rare and not without danger, it is sometimes used e.g. to make sure that things are deleted in a chain in the right order. So you stop the chain of deletes if you failed to delete a child. It has a name, but I cannot remember exactly what this pattern is called right now.

Answer (score 2):

This is my understanding about the topic:
Generally Listener/call-back methods don't need to return anything and they are called in response to an event.
e.g. `onClick()` method of `OnClickListener`.

```
OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //some click handling code
    }
};
```

But if they are part of an event-chain then a boolean return type is used to either abort of continue the execution of events. e.g. `onDrag()` method from `OnDragListener`.

```
OnDragListener onDragListener = new OnDragListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        //some drag handling code
        return false;
    }
}
```

Documentation of this method says "return true if the drag event was handled successfully, or false if the drag event was not handled. Note that false will trigger the `View` to call its `onDragEvent()` handler."
so it is not very uncommon to have return in call-back/event-handling methods if they are part of chain of events. And what should be returned is part of the documentation of the API.